# Xfce4, показать картинку на рабочем столе

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce4

На рабочем столе лежит картинка:

```
$ ls -la ~/Desktop
.rw-rw-r-- 3,8k USER 27 мая 14:07 traffic-monthly.png
```

Показывется она как иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но хотелось бы видеть целиком, и не как фон рабочего стола, независимо (картинка искуственная, нагимпил):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока единственный вариант придумался - conky. Но что-то не лежит к нему душа: ради такой мелочи тащить столько зависимостей. Есть ещё варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки [conky](https://conky.cc/) - похоже, лучший вариант. Чтобы не тащить лишние зависимости, можно воспользоваться AppImage (выкладывается на [github](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/releases/)). Минимальный конфиг для моего случая:

```
conky.config = 
{
  update_interval        = 600,
  -- расстояние от левого и нижнего края экрана:
  gap_x                  = 2,
  gap_y                  = 2,
  -- совпадает с реальными размерами картинки:
  minimum_width          = 500,
  minimum_height         = 200,
  own_window             = true,
  own_window_type        = 'desktop', 
  own_window_transparent = true,
};
conky.text = [[
${image /tmp/traffic-monthly.png -p 0,0 -s 500x200}
]];
```